# How to add async functionality to a Firebase 'put' and 'set' query operation

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have been using the following function to store a file in Firebase Storage, return the URL, which I then store along with some other fields, in Firestore.

Where do I add an 'await' or how do I add a promise so that the 'history.push("/") is not called until all operations have completed? At the moment I think it's pushing me on to the next page before it's finished.

```
async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const collectionRef = useFireStore.collection('users').doc(`${currentUser.uid}`);
    const storageRef = useStorage.ref("avatars")
    const fileRef = storageRef.child(`${uuidv4()}`)

    fileRef.put(file).then(() => {
        fileRef.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
            collectionRef.set({
                createdAt: timestamp(),
                email: currentUser.email,
                userid: currentUser.uid,
                username: username,
                firstname: firstname,
                lastname: lastname,
                avatar: url
            })
        });
    })
    history.push("/")
}
```

What would be some best-practices here, please?
Kind regards, Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const collectionRef = useFireStore.collection('users').doc(`${currentUser.uid}`);
    const storageRef = useStorage.ref("avatars")
    const fileRef = storageRef.child(`${uuidv4()}`)

    await fileRef.put(file);
    const url = await fileRef.getDownloadURL();
    await collectionRef.set({
       createdAt: timestamp(),
       email: currentUser.email,
       userid: currentUser.uid,
       username: username,
       firstname: firstname,
       lastname: lastname,
       avatar: url
    });
    history.push("/")
}
```

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Brilliant Shri, it works perfectly now. Many thanks. Previously, functions on the page I was pushing to were breaking because the function I posted above hadn't finished. All good now. Thanks again.